# Spring @ConfigurationProperties not mapping list of objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am facing strange issue with spring property mapper. I have yml contains list of values. I want convert that to list of object why building application. So, i used @ConfigurationProperties. With this i am able to map simple types. when i use this to complex type(list of objects) it failed. No exception, but values list is zero when i debug. please find below yml and java files. I tried with spring 2.0.0,2.0.1,2.0.2,2.0.3 No success. Can any one have idea to fix it?

application.yml

```
acme:
  list:
    - name: my name
      description: my description
    - name: another name
      description: another description
```

AcmeProperties.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration/yml/application.yml")
public class AcmeProperties {

    private final List<MyPojo> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<MyPojo> getList() {
        return this.list;
    }

    static class MyPojo {
        private String name;
        private String description;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }
}
```

With setter and getter methods:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme")
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration/yml/application.yml")
public class AcmeProperties {

    private List<MyPojo> list;

    public List<MyPojo> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<MyPojo> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static class MyPojo {
        private String name;
        private String description;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of this class:

```
@Autowired
public HomeController(AppProperties appProperties, AcmeProperties acmeProperties) {
    this.appProperties = appProperties;
    this.acmeProperties = acmeProperties;
}
```

Comment: could try `public static class MyPojo`, and put `set` methods on it.  And same with `list`: make that non final, don't inialise it, and have a setter for it

Comment: @MrSpoon, No success

Comment: I tried your code with setter and getter at a spring boot application and it worked... so i doupt it is in these classes the problem.
You do not create and AcmeProperties bean manually or via new, right?
spring boot version?
one extra info. i ommited @PropertySource("classpath:configuration/yml/application.yml") i have put it in my application.yml in resources folder. Can you try that for debuging reasons? just in case..

Comment: @Alexandros, I am not creating AcmeProperties bean manually. I autowired that in my controller. I updated my question with usage please check.

Comment: @Alexandros, I am using spring-boot 2.0.3. Can you post your changes in answer. or update question with your changes?

Comment: The think is i made no changes.. you place this yml file under resources/configuration/yml/ directory?

Comment: I think Liping Huang is correct...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is `PropertySource` only support the properties file, you cannot read the value from `yml` file. you can update it like:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
@PropertySource("classpath:/configuration/yml/test.properties")
class AcmeProperties {
```

**configuration/yml/test.properties**

```
acme.list[0].name=my name
acme.list[0].description=my description
acme.list[1].name=another name
acme.list[1].description=another description
```

and the code should work.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) (emphasis is mine) :

> **24.6.4 YAML Shortcomings**
>
> **YAML files cannot be loaded by using the @PropertySource annotation**.
>   So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use
>   a properties file.

But you provided a yml file to `@PropertySource` :

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme")
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration/yml/application.yml")
public class AcmeProperties { ...}
```

So you have two possibilities :

- this yml file is a Spring Boot profile properties file : enable this profile before executing the application and so remove `@PropertySource`
- this yml file is not a Spring Boot profile properties file : use a properties file instead of a yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with
    `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme")`

Based on:
https://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/injecting-list-with-spring-from-yaml/

Comment: It is the same thing. The `value()` of the enum is an alias for `prefix`

Comment: @James, No success

Comment: Oh ok, so maybe formatting in .yml is wrong. This little boy is sensitive for this things

Comment: No formatting is good, when i give simple type it is accepting.

Comment: I followed this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-complex-type-merge)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that resource is not found as specified at @PropertySource("classpath:configuration/yml/application.yml"). -made the same mistake when tried to debug your code..-
Could you please put a break point in 
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser#processPropertySource
with watch check path returned from 
this.resourceLoader.getResource(resolvedLocation).getFile().

In my case i have: C:\Users\user12\Desktop\hibernate\out\production\classes\configuration\application.yml

there there is not application.yml...

I think you do not see exception because spring has 
if (ignoreResourceNotFound) {..} else {throw ex} in this method

Comment: If resource not found spring application wont run. In my local i am able run application and fetch simple types from the yml file

Comment: @Component
@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
public class AcmeProperties {
...
}

and add one application.yml under resources folder.