# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method: Could not resolve placeholder @PropertySource("classpath:dev.yml")

Tags: spring-boot, cron, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to load the following cron-execution-expression:

```
---
####################### Cron-Job Every 2mins every day #######################
cron:
  exe:
    expression: 0 0/2 * * * ?
```

The catch is, the above cron-expression is in a Spring-Cloud-Config (Let's say Springboot Project A, running on port: 8001) github repository. named: microservice-dev.yml

Project B (port: 8002) loads all the configurations provided by Project A at startup & I'm happy with that. But how do I locate this expression?

> ${cron.exe.expression}

```
@Component
//Couldn't get it to work with Spring-Cloud-Config
@PropertySource("classpath:microservice-dev.yml")
public class MergeCachedRecordsToDBImpl {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MergeCachedRecordsToDBImpl.class);

    //Couldn't get it to work with Spring-Cloud Config
    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.exe.expression}")
    public void purgeExpired() {
        LOGGER.info("Cron-Job Notification....");
        LOGGER.info("Cron-Job executed at: {}", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    }
}
```

At some point, I got it to work, but I'm not sure how? I'm trying to retrace my steps.

Now I'm getting this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'purgeExpired': Could not resolve placeholder 'cron.exe.expression' in value "${cron.exe.expression}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it to work again with the .yml file. Happy Days.

In the following .yml file:

> src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml

has the following contents:

```
---
spring:
  application:
    name: leaderboard
  profiles:
    active: dev

server:
  port: 8004

---
####################### Cron-Job Every 2mins every day #######################
cron:
  exe:
    expression: 0 0/2 * * * ?
```

in the code, I annotated my class and method with following annotations:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:bootstrap.yml")
public class CronClass{
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronClass.class);

   @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.exe.expression}")
   private void cornJob(){
        LOGGER.info("Cron-Job Notification....");
        LOGGER.info("Cron-Job executed at: {}", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
   }
}
```

Results:

```
2018-09-29 11:19:00.007  INFO [leaderboard,66037f3d8052cf6b,66037f3d8052cf6b,false] 7937 --- [   scheduling-1] i.s.l.task.CronClass    : Cron-Job Notification....
2018-09-29 11:19:00.007  INFO [leaderboard,66037f3d8052cf6b,66037f3d8052cf6b,false] 7937 --- [   scheduling-1] i.s.l.task.CronClass    : Cron-Job executed at: 2018-09-29 11:19:00.007
```

---

```
2018-09-29 11:20:00.000  INFO [leaderboard,25cab214549b76a6,25cab214549b76a6,false] 7937 --- [   scheduling-1] i.s.l.task.CronClass    : Cron-Job Notification....
2018-09-29 11:20:00.000  INFO [leaderboard,25cab214549b76a6,25cab214549b76a6,false] 7937 --- [   scheduling-1] i.s.l.task.CronClass    : Cron-Job executed at: 2018-09-29 11:20:00.0
```

---

```
2018-09-29 11:21:00.000  INFO [leaderboard,c2f241d8a806fd26,c2f241d8a806fd26,false] 7937 --- [   scheduling-1] i.s.l.task.CronClass    : Cron-Job Notification....
2018-09-29 11:21:00.000  INFO [leaderboard,c2f241d8a806fd26,c2f241d8a806fd26,false] 7937 --- [   scheduling-1] i.s.l.task.CronClass    : Cron-Job executed at: 2018-09-29 11:21:00.0
```

[image: Evidence of .yml file with @PropertySource]

Answer (score 1):

Currently the spring boot `@PropertySource` doesn't support the yaml as the property file.

Here is the similar question - [Spring @ConfigurationProperties not mapping list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378768/spring-configurationproperties-not-mapping-list-of-objects)

Comment: Thank you @liping-huang But by the time the springboot application loads, it already has the configurations. Surely, there's something we can do to extract the cron-expression.

Comment: Oh, I got it to work again. :-)  Instead of putting in on the Spring-Cloud-Config github repo. I've placed it in the following directory path:

src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml & works like a charm. Springframework Guru mentioned that Spring can interpret both .yml and .properties as the same.

Comment: @S34N Cool, that's great.